# Getting the "bytes-like object is required" error, but the fix causes a "write() arguments must be str" error

Tags: python-3.x

This is a piece of a script that is giving me fits.  If I use 'wb', I get the "bytes like" error.  If I change it to 'w', I get the "write() arguments" error.

```
with open(output_path+filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write('<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n')
    f.write(ET.tostring(elem, pretty_print = True))
```

If I have 'wb', it gives me this error:

```
    f.write("<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

If I have 'w', it gives me:

```
    f.write(ET.tostring(elem, pretty_print = True))
TypeError:  write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

The reason I'm doing it like this, is because I'm using lxml to take one HUGE XML sheet with several files'-worth of metadata and split it up into several XML files.  So the like with the UTF-8 encoding is so that each individual file, has that written at the top.  Without posting a ton of code, ET = lxml.etree.

Comment: Which gives you the arguments error? And can you paste the whole error?

Comment: If you want to use wb, then encode the string when you write it. f.write("some string".encode("utf8"))

Comment: Why you write xml directly? There is a tool for thst

Comment: matt, 'w' gives me this:  f.write(ET.tostring(elem, pretty_print = True)) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes.

Comment: 'wb' gives me: f.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>/n") TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Swift, I'm using lxml.  This is just part of the whole thing.

Comment: matt, as far as encoding the string, I need the "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>/n" line to appear exactly like that.  <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>/n.  It was working fine with Python 2.  This has been something that changed since I moved to 3.